Is decomposability of polynomials over a field an undecidable problem?
By a decomposition of a polynomial $F(x)$ over a field $K$ we mean writing $F(x)$ as
$$
F(x)=G(H(x)) \quad(G(x), H(x) \in K[x]),
$$
which is nontrivial if $\operatorname{deg} G(x)>1$ and $\operatorname{deg} H(x)>1$. The polynomial $F(x)$ is called decomposable over $K$ if it has at least one nontrivial decomposition over $K$; otherwise it is said to be indecomposable.
Motivated by my previous question, I want to know if the decision problem of "Given an arbitrary polynomial $F(x)\in K[x]$, is it decomposable over $K$ or not?" is decidable or undecidable.
I am interested in the above question because of the famous Bilu–Tichy Theorem.

The title of this question, which was identical to that of your previous question, mentions the specific field $K = \mathbb Q$ and restricts to integer polynomials, but your body doesn't.  Is that intentional?  (Since the Unicode letters ℤ and ℚ that you used, I guess to evade the duplicate filter, looked distractingly different on my machine, I re-worded to avoid them.  I hope this was all right; but, if you didn't mean to restrict to this case, then you can change the title to something more accurate.)

@LSpice: Do you mean the linked previous question, or was there a deleted question I'm not seeing? It looks to me like the titles were different - the previous question was about reducibility, rather than decomposability.

@user2357112, re, yes, you are right, my mistake. Then I'm definitely not sure why the Unicode was used!

@LSpice I am sorry, it was a mistake from my side because of copy-paste. I will edit my question now.

Yes, this problem is decidable. Kozen and Landau gave a polynomial-time algorithm that tests if a polynomial $F$ is decomposable and produces a nontrivial decomposition $F(x) = G(H(x))$ if one exists. Their algorithm requires that $\deg(G)$ has a multiplicative inverse in $K$.
Kozen, Dexter; Landau, Susan, Polynomial decomposition algorithms, J. Symb. Comput. 7, No. 5, 445-456 (1989); errata ibid. 10, No. 5, 529 (1990). ZBL0691.68030.

What happens if $\deg(G)$ is not invertible in $K$?
